# How to parse a file using shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I am having a file :

```
abc@gmail.com
dba@gmail.com
xyz@gmail.com
//abc@gmail.com
//dba@gmail.com
//xyz@gmail.com
abc@gmail.com
dba@gmail.com
xyz@gmail.com
```

I want to write a script which parse the file and for the first occurrence of say abc@gmail it should remain as it is and for other occurrence if "//" found then ok otherwise add "//" at the starting of all other occurrence.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you wish to achieve. Can you provide sample *output* (the result you aim with this input).

Comment: S/he wants to comment out all lines that were seen before, unless already commented out.

Comment: sample output: abc@gmail.com
dba@gmail.com
xyz@gmail.com
//abc@gmail.com
//dba@gmail.com
//xyz@gmail.com
//abc@gmail.com
//dba@gmail.com
//xyz@gmail.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk '$1 in seen && !/^[[:blank:]]*\/\// { $0 = "//" $0 } !seen[$1]++{} 1' file
abc@gmail.com
dba@gmail.com
xyz@gmail.com
//abc@gmail.com
//dba@gmail.com
//xyz@gmail.com
//abc@gmail.com
//dba@gmail.com
//xyz@gmail.com
```

Comment: thanks anubhava ..... i would request you to help me in learning shell script i know a few basics but for complex things i just need google or platform like stackoverflow... could you please suggest any tutorials or books which i can refer...Thank you so much..

Comment: I just search good tutorials online. Start [with this one](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html)